PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create"
I'm trying to schedule a task from a node.js service running on GKE Autopilot. I'm scheduling it with the @google-cloud/tasks npm package.
I am getting this error:
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create" for the resource "projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/queues/my-queue" (or the resource may not exist).
    at callErrorFromStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:82:17)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:360:55)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:458:34)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:419:48)
    at /app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:163:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

I have made sure the service account associated to my cluster has access to the cloud tasks admin role. I don't understand if for some reason @google-cloud/tasks is not using the correct account or if I'm doing something else wrong.

When I use the "ghcr.io/aertje/cloud-tasks-emulator emulator and with it everything works.
Edit: I added the cloud tasks admin role to every account and it still fails...

Your question lacks sufficient detail to answer. Are you using Workload Identity Federation for GKE to associate your Kubernetes Service Accounts with Google IAM Service Accounts?

I'm using Autopilot so it should be enabled by default

It is good practice to prove your assertions: (1) "I made sure the service account associated to my cluster"  -- show what you did; (2)  the error includes "projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/queues/my-queue" (or the resource may not exist). -- show that this is untrue.

I added a screenshot where all the accounts permissions are visible.

Does your Node.JS Resource use the default Service Account? I don't recall whether the default Service Account is bound to Google IAM roles by default. If you are using a user-defined Service Account (or if default doesn't inherit -- as I suspect) IAM bindings, have you made the bindings? This appears to have evolved since I last programmed it and now you use the Kubernetes Service Account directly in gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding directly rather than (as I have) annotations on the Kubernetes Service Account to associate it with a Google IAM Service Account.

I'm not sure tbh, I deploy an alpine node image to GKE, I don't even understand how my node.js code is supposed to authenticate this way, I would expect I have to provide my image the required credentials

Always good "tbh" :-) This is non-trivial but it's actually a really elegant solution. Here's the documentation Configure Apps to use GKE Workload Identity Federation

Google provides a powerful auth mechanism called Application Default Credentials that automates the way apps built using Google SDKs, authenticate; in essence much of the work is done (securely) and automatically.

With your app on GKE AutoPilot using WIF ... your code uses the SDK which talks to the Kubernetes metadata service (which is configured by AutoPilot) to talk to the Google metadata service (which you configure using the link I sent) to permit your app's Kubernetes Service Account to be authorized to the appropriate IAM permissions against the Cloud Tasks service. The process is straightforward but has multiple steps. Once you build a model for the flow (and once you've done it a couple of times), it becomes easier and it's much better than alternatives.

Thanks, do you know if I have to re-deploy the nodes after I followed the instructions?

No. Application Default Credentials effectively abstracts auth from your code and from the services (GKE, Cloud Tasks) etc. And so, changes have a small propagation delay but no redeployment|recreation is necessary; it will "just work" when you configure it correctly.

This would be an excellent use-case for Google to apply Gemini so that it could walk you through (or apply for you) the steps needed based on a dialog.

It's still failing, I don't really know what else to do at this point.

I encourage you to try this example which runs through the entire process of having a Pod access a Cloud Storage bucket. This mirrors your approach and should help you understand where you're going wrong. Also review Workload Identity Federation for GKE which is a decent overview.

Ah I made it!!! I had to use the correct command  gcloud tasks queues add-iam-policy-binding

Super! :-) Now document what you did :-)
